# How to create a generic structure in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct

I'm currently writing a program that basically logs data from multiple peripherals. Since I'm logging the same data from each peripheral, I saw this as a good opportunity to encapsulate this data in a structure. I originally envisioned doing this with a "C" style structure, but when I dug into MATLAB's documentation, I realized the syntax is quite different.

To be more specific, I need - in MATLAB's conventions - a 1-by-6 structure. If I were using C, I would simply define a structure prototype, and create as many instances of it as I needed. Ideally, this allows me to cleanly organize my code.

However, MATLAB doesn't seem to provide this capability. For instance, this is one way I saw how to do what I want:

```
patient.name = 'John Doe';
patient.billing = 1;

%Create a second "instance"
patient.name(2) = 'Someone else';
patient.billing(2) = 2;
```

The method above does work, being that I can add as many instances as I want. Still, I'm wondering if I could simply define a generic structure with the fields I already need? If I can, this would allow me to better distinguish between the different peripherals while maintaining cleaner and easier to follow code.

Any constructive input is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make structs in a similar way to `c` if you would like.

```
patient.name(2) = 'Someone else';
patient.billing(2) = 2;
```

This is simply making the elements of a struct into arrays. If you want to make an array of structs you would do this:

```
patient(2).name = 'Someone else';
patient(2).billing = 2;
```

If you want to make a struct with fields that you need you can do this:

```
function outstruct = createstruct(name, billing history, age)
    outstruct = struct('name', name, 'billing', billing, 'hist ...
end
```

Although it would be just as easy to add that to the body of the code without the function.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - I hadn't noticed the distinction before. However, when I think of a `C` structure, I tend to think of it in terms of a `typedef`. That is, tyepdef struct {...} MyDef. This way I have all the parameters of the structure generically defined, and I can create as many instances of it as I like. For instance, MyDef PerphOne, MyDef PerphTwo, etc.

Comment: @Mlagma I have added some detail that would allow you to do that. Hopefully that clears it up.

Comment: @Mlagma: in MATLAB, you can dynamically add fields to a structure. For instance this is valid code: `s = struct(); s.x = 1; s.y = 'hello';`. In addition you can create an *array of structures* just like C as explained above.